# Swipe view to read next news

Tags: android, android-intent, swipe

I use an Adapter extends BaseAdapter to show all news by using a ListView in a fragment (NewsListFragment). And to read each news I use an Intent to call a DetailActivity.class. If user want to read next news he come back to listview to click on next or previous news an so on. 
My question is when you have the detail of a new ;  how read next or previous news by juste SWIPE left or right view.

Here my **NewsListFragment** code

```
    private List<News_Item> array=new ArrayList<>();
....

 lv=(ListView)Npages.findViewById(R.id.list_new_item);
        adapter=new NewsMain_Adapter(getActivity(),array);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String title= ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.letitre)).getText().toString();
                String body= ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.content)).getText().toString();

        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);

        i.putExtra("title", title);
                i.putExtra("content", body);

                startActivity(i);

 }
        });
....
```

**DetailActivity.class** code

```
  final TextView lbtitle= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.letitre);
  final TextView lbbody = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lcontent);

Intent i = getIntent();
String title = i.getStringExtra("title");
String content= i.getStringExtra("content");

lbtitle.setText(title);
lbbody.setText(content);

...
```

**Adapter.class** code

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<News_Item> items;
    ImageLoader imageLoader=AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public Adapter (Activity activity,List<News_Item> items){
        this.activity=activity;
        this.items =items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(inflater==null){
            inflater=(LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_news_rows,null);
        }
        if(imageLoader==null)
            imageLoader=AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        TextView titre =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.letitre);
        TextView contenu =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.contenu);

        //getting data for row
        News_Item item=items.get(position);

        //tittre
        titre.setText(item.getTitle());
        //content
        contenu.setText(item.getContenu());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I have to use **OnSwipeTouchListener** in my DetailActivity.class but I need your help. 
Thanks to light my way please.

Comment: use viewpager for that

Comment: You can pass your array to DetailActivity.class so then you just need to implement a viewpager after that.

Comment: Thanks. How pass array to the DetailActivity.class. Please can you give me an example code or a link.

Comment: I use viewpager and also FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Thanks guys.